# Fetch data from database in decending in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a website in codeigniter. In the main page i am fetching all data from database. I want to fetch my database in a decending order according to id. I think its a small thing but i encounterd some error in my code. I have tried some similar questions but i got this type error.

**what i have tried**

**user.php**(controller)

```
public function viewmainoffer()
{
    $this->load->model('viewoffer');
    $employee = $this->viewoffer->veiwoffersmodel();
    $this->load->view('user/offer', ['employee'=>$employee]);
}
```

**viewoffer.php**(model)

```
  public function veiwoffersmodel() { 
        return $this->db->get('offers')->order_by('offer_id', 'desc')->result(); 
      
      
    }
```

**offer.php**(view)

```
<?php if(count($employee)): ?> 
  <?php foreach ($employee as $row): ?>

    <div class="container mainofferdiv align-left p-3 mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 imagedivision ">
      <img style="border-radius: 10px;" height="100" width="150" class="mt-5  offerimage" src="<?=  $row->image ?>">
    <br>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8  d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
      <h3 style="color: red;" class="mt-3"><?=  $row->heading ?></h3>
      <p style="word-wrap: break-word;"><?php echo nl2br($row->details); ?></p>
      <div>
      
        <a class="btn btn-warning p-3 font-weight-bold" href="<?=  $row->link ?>">Collect cashback</a>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <br>
     <button class="btn btn-success"> Verified <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

    
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**the error i have got**

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::order_by()

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\application\models\viewoffer.php

Line Number: 25

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\application\controllers\user.php
Line: 122
Function: veiwoffersmodel

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Thankyou

Comment: Move the order by before the get. Otherwise, you're trying to use the database ordering function on the results after it's retrieved from the database instead of before.

Comment: Thankyou.....it works

Comment: @aynber, write an answer with sample, so it can be accepted.

Comment: @biesior I voted as a typo, but sure

Comment: @aynber Actually I wouldn't consider it as a typo. It's rather misunderstanding and should be explained IMHO. thx.

Comment: @biesior Hmm, good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need switch the get and order by. Get returns the results, so you need to place the `order_by` before the `get` so it can be run on the database, instead of the final results.

```
return $this->db->order_by('offer_id', 'desc')->get('offers')->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your function in your Model (viewoffer.php)

```
public function veiwoffersmodel() { 
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table name');
$this->db->order_by('offer_id', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```